# XE4 Deployment error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, firemonkey-fm2

Good afternoon all. Apologies if SO isn't the place to ask, I wasn't sure there was an 'errors stack exchange' or such, and whether or not any XE4 users would be visitors there.

I'm currently trying out the XE4 trial, and I'm wanting to see just whether the iOS implementation is as easy as they made it look.

I've got my remote profile all setup and working, and I've made a small application that only contains a progress bar. Now, when I deploy that application to the simulator, it runs on the iOS simulator as expected.

However, when I try to deploy to a device, I get the following error;

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:\Users\Scott\Documents\RAD Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS5.0.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks'
```

I've tried Debug, Ad-hoc, and App Store profiles, but they all return the same error. The folder 'PrivateFrameworks' doesn't even exist. There's one called 'Frameworks' in the 'Library' folder, but nothing else. I considered that maybe it's an incorrect SDK library path, but the only one with such a path is 'UIFoundation'. Changing the path to 'frameworks' like the others are returns this;

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: can't parse __DATA/__objc_imageinfo section in C:\Users\Scott\Documents\RAD Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
```

That file DOES exist (99KB) but the error remains (and so I assume that changing the SDK lib path wasn't the right thing to do). It's like it's not even attempting to deploy over to the mac for compilation due to a file or folder issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the checklist in the [Troubleshooting: Cannot Deploy to the iOS Device](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/RunIOSDeviceFailedHelpPage) help topic.

1. If you have not run your iOS app on the iOS Simulator, make sure you satisfy the requirements here:

   - Troubleshooting: Cannot Deploy to the iOS Simulator
2. Make sure your iOS device is connected to your Mac by USB cable.
3. Specify the iOS Device as the target platform in the Project Manager.
4. Complete the Provisioning page. (Your developer certificate is required for code signing)
5. Set the required Project Options for your iOS app:

   - Specify your application icons - Application Options.
   - Specify info.plist keys such as UIDeviceFamily - Version Info.
6. Install the Xcode command-line tools on your Mac. (Required for code signing your iOS app)

There are links in the documentation above with details about some of the steps involved.

Comment: I don't believe it's actually an issue with the setup simply because the errors appear in the RAD Studio IDE console (along with the compile dialog informing me that an error occurred), and there's no evidence of anything even happening over on the mac.

Comment: The IDE deploys to the Mac in order to run in the simulator. If there's an issue with the files that need to go to the Mac, you get errors in the IDE. IOW, follow the troubleshooting steps, whether you believe it or not. :-) There are configuration things to do on both the Mac and PC sides.

Answer (score 1):

I had extactly the same issue. It happened when trtying to deploy to the iOS 5.0 simulator (not even an iOS device).
It appears that UIFoundations (PrivateFrameworks) gets pulled across and cached when you setup the SDK for iOS 6.1 on XE4.
Make sure the sumulators are installed on Xcode in preferences. Restart Xcode (make sure the PA server is running). Setup a connection profile with the 6.1 SDK in options on XE4 and it works.
Hope this makes sense but it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing framework into your SDK. Tools->Options->SDK Manager, go to Frameworks and click the yellow button. Also remember to press "Update Local File Cache" after you're done. You will find that you will need to fetch more Frameworks and Libraries in the future.

[image: SDK Manager - Frameworks]