# XE4 iOS App: Deploy to iOS device failes

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I want to test my first app on my iPhone, not only on the simulator. Xcode and paserver are running. All the license stuff is done. If I choose "My-iOS-Device" as the target platform in Delphi XE4 and press "run", I get the following error:

> [DCC Fehler] E2597 ld: library not found for -lcompiler_rt
>
> [DCC Fataler Fehler] F2588 Linker-Fehlercode: 1 ($00000001)

I have no idea what this error means. My PC is connected to my iMac via ethernet. Deploying to the simulator is no problem. If I cut all connections to the iMac, I get the same error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XE4 Deployment error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303294/xe4-deployment-error)

Comment: Mhm, no. That's not the same problem :(

Comment: It's the same solution. Follow the troubleshooting steps. Because you've done "the license stuff" doesn't mean you've done everything else that's mentioned there. The basic problem is the same: "Deployment to the iOS device fails. How do I figure out how to fix it?" I posted an answer there that's pretty detailed as to what steps you need to follow, along with links to the documentation that details the specifics of those steps.

Comment: I already followed these steps. The problem is that delphi not event tries to connect to the paserver.

Comment: If you followed those steps exactly, Delphi would be trying to connect, which means you did not follow all of the steps. We can't see your machine from here, and we can't read your mind to see exactly what step you missed. The question remains the same, as does the answer. :-)

Comment: If deployment to simulator works, then yes, it's a provisioning profile issue. So yes, it's a duplicate.

Comment: Muhahaha, I've got it! You are wrong. There were missing a few paths (Tools->Options->Delphi options->library)

Comment: Could you answer your own question, please. From the deleted "answers" on your question, which you can't seen. "I am having the exact same problem. Can you please provide some more details on how you fixed the problem? What paths did you include?"