# Can't Find Directory Library\PrivateFrameworks XE8 64 Bit iPhoneOS9

Tags: delphi, app-store, 64-bit, delphi-xe8

I have been developing a mobile app using Delphi XE8 and testing under the platform:

> IOS Device - 32 Bit - iPhoneOS 8.4.

Now that I am happy with the app I am trying to deploy it to the app store. From what I understand, in order to do this, I have to submit a 64 bit Build. Therefore, I am trying to build my app using:

> IOS Device - 64 bit - iPhoneOS 9.0

When I compile or Build the project in 64 bit I get the error message:

> [DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:\Users\leonard\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS9.0.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks'
>         ld: file not found: /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib

I have tried deleting and re-adding the SDK and selecting the 'Update Local File Cache' for iPhoneOS 9.0.

The closest thing I could find on google was this link:
[XE4 Deployment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303294/xe4-deployment-error)
But that did not help. There were other suggestions that dealt with xcode but they do not look like they apply to my situation either.

It would be appreciated if someone can offer a suggestion as to why I am getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you read the section in the documentation about how to provision and deploy an iOS application to the Apple Store?

Comment: I have been using the documentation to get to the point I'm at currently. As far as I can tell I have completed all the required steps and completed all the prerequisites. I believe my provisioning is correct but even if it was not, I would not expect to get this error on my build. I tried compiling some of the supplied sample apps in IOS Device 64bit and get the same error. So I searched for the PrivateFrameworks directory on my development PC and only found it in the OS8.1 and OS8.4 SDK directories. I do not know why it does not exist for OS9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't discover why my PrivateFrameworks directory was missing. But I decided to move my app to Delphi 10 Seattle. After installing Seattle and configuring my application platforms, I then had the required directories. I was able to build my application in 64 bit and got an .ipa file in preperation for submission to the App store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because of changes in the iOS SDK 9. There is workaround for building iOS 32-bit applications for iOS 9 with XE7 and XE8 suggested in [blog of Embarcadero Community](https://community.embarcadero.com/answers/xe8-ios9-e2597-ld-file-not-found-usr-lib-libiconv-dylib/latest). But I am not sure if this workaround suitable for 64 bit..